# How do I send a custom file type using Intents?

Tags: android

I have built an app that generates JSON files that store app data with a custom file extension. I'm currently using a standard ACTION_SEND intent and adding the Uri to the world readable file. I tried setting the type as application/json however this brought up an error saying that 'No applications can perform this action'. Would it be more effective not to send a MIME type even though I have code for detecting files coming into the app with a specific type. Is there a better way of doing this sharing procedure?

Answer (score 0):

```
 I'm currently using a standard ACTION_SEND intent and adding the Uri to the world readable file. I tried setting the type as application/JSON however this brought up an error saying that 'No applications can perform this action'.
```

In android I didn't find any application which displayed `JSON` file as a Viewer document. May be its available, If available then just install it in your device and check the mime type which it responds to View particular `JSON` file.

Its better to parse this `JSON` file and make (Convert) it to `Text` or `HTML` file, then using `Intent` with `ACTION_VIEW` you can view this file in many pre-installed application on your device..

Comment: Would this bring up sharing options so that the data can be sent via email/Bluetooth? Ideally the data shouldn't be viewable by other apps.

Comment: If your JSON file is Converted to Text or HTML then you have all option available to View or Share files with other apps.

Comment: It seems that it works OK in the emulator if you use a MIME type of */* - this will happily launch the messaging app so I assume this is OK.